# Loading image from the filesystem doesn't work in Qt stylesheets

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I am trying to load image as background from a file located on filesystem and it doesn't show up.
If I do the same thing from resource file it works without any problem (with :/..).
Why would that be an issues, what am I missing?

QT 5.11.2 MinGw 32bit.

Code is:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->label->setStyleSheet("border-image: url(file:///c:/flags/country.png);");
}
```

EDIT #1:

As proposed I have added path checking like:

const QUrl url("file:///C:/flags/country.png");

```
if (!url.isValid()) {
    qDebug("-------------------------------- Invalid URL: %s", qUtf8Printable(url.toString()));
}else{
    qDebug() << " ----------------- PATH IS OK! -----------------------------";
}
```

And it returns PATH IS OK!... which makes it even stranger.

Comment: Maybe you could check the path syntax with a QUrl object to be sure your image is found by Qt https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#details

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->label->setStyleSheet("border-image: url(c:/flags/country.png);"); <------- without file
}
```